# sed remove '_ipx/xxx/' from "/_ipx/xxx/images/img.webp"

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to figure out the regex command using `sed` to replace the `_ipx/xxx/` with nothing, so the `src` ends up as just `images/logo.webp`.

As an example, if I have the following img tag in `index.html`:

```html
<img src="/_ipx/w_253,f_webp,q_80/images/img.webp"
alt="Testing a Custom Component"
sizes="(max-width: 640px) 100vw, 33vw"
srcset="/_ipx/w_640,f_webp,q_80/images/img.webp 640w, /_ipx/w_253,f_webp,q_80/images/img.webp 253w" />
```

I want the sed to replace it to be:

```html
<img src="/images/img.webp"
alt="Testing a Custom Component"
sizes="(max-width: 640px) 100vw, 33vw"
srcset="/images/img.webp 640w, /images/img.webp 253w" />
```

According to https://regex101.com, I think the following should do it: `/_ipx\/.+?\//gi`. However, when I try using it, nothing happens:

`sed -i '' -e 's/_ipx\/.+?\//test/gi' index.html`

Comment: The basic problem is that you are trying to use a PCRE regex with `sed`, which does not accept this modern regex dialect. In particular, the non-greedy `.+?` is not supported by `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this `sed` command:

```bash
sed 's~/_ipx/[^/]*~~g' index.html

<img src="/images/img.webp"
alt="Testing a Custom Component"
sizes="(max-width: 640px) 100vw, 33vw"
srcset="/images/img.webp 640w, /images/img.webp 253w" />
```

However do keep in mind that it will replace `/_ipx/...` everywhere not just inside few attributes.

To keep replacements only within `src` or `srcset` attributes, use:

```bash
sed -E -e ':a' -e 's~((srcset|src)="[^"]*)/_ipx/[^/]*~\1~g;ta' index.html

<img src="/images/img.webp"
alt="Testing a Custom Component"
sizes="(max-width: 640px) 100vw, 33vw"
srcset="/images/img.webp 640w, /images/img.webp 253w" />
```

Note that we have to use a `label` and `jump-to` feature here as we have to make sure to match and replace **within `srcset`or `src` ** attributes only not everywhere.